# Como saber a direção do mouse?

Tags: python, teclado, cursor, posição-do-cursor, pynput

Eu gostaria de fazer um programa que indicasse para que posição o mouse está se movendo (direita, esquerda, alto, baixo, direita e alto, direita e baixo...), mas não consigo chega a uma lógica que me dê esse resultado.

Exemplos:
Se o Y e X estão sendo incrementado, então o mouse estará indo para cima e para direita ao mesmo tempo. Se apenas o X está sendo incrementado, então o mouse estará indo para direita. Se o X está sendo decrementado, o mouse estará indo para esquerda. E assim por diante.

[image: Amostra]

Eu já pensei diversas maneiras, mas nada funciona.

```
import pynput

def Position():
    mouse = pynput.mouse.Controller()
    while True:
        position_anterior = mouse.position[0] #mouse.position retorna uma tupla com (x, y)
        position_atual = mouse.position[0]
        if position_atual > position_anterior: #
            print("direita")
        elif position_atual < position_anterior:
            print("esquerda")
        elif position_atual == position_anterior:
            print("parado")
Position()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem que comparar com a posição anterior, não duas vezes com a mesma.

Algo assim:

```
    import pynput

    def Position():
        mouse = pynput.mouse.Controller()
        position_anterior = mouse.position[0]

        while True:
            position_atual = mouse.position[0]
            if position_atual > position_anterior:
                print("direita")
            elif position_atual < position_anterior:
                print("esquerda")
            elif position_atual == position_anterior:
                print("parado")
            position_anterior = position_atual

    Position()
```